# Standard citation with \volcite

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am using `biblatex` to manage my citations and bibliography.

I'd like to use `\volcite` to cite a specific volume of a multi-volume work, but with a standard look for the citation itself. E.g. for the numeric style normal citations look like

```
[1]
```

but with e.g. `\volcite{3}{Smith}` I get by default (with German localization).

```
[1, Bd. 3]
```

How do I get the \volcite citation to look like the normal one?

Side note: The bibliography entry should not be modified, only the citation.

EDIT: Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[
    backend = biber,
    style = numeric-comp
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@MvBook{Kohl,
  author    = {Kohlrausch, F.},
  title     = {Praktische Physik},
  volumes   = {3}
}
@Book{Kohl1,
  author    = {Kohlrausch, F.},
  title     = {Praktische Physik},
  volumes   = {3},
  volume    = {1}
}
@Book{Kohl2,
  author    = {Kohlrausch, F.},
  title     = {Praktische Physik},
  volumes   = {3},
  volume    = {2}
}
@Book{Kohl3,
  author    = {Kohlrausch, F.},
  title     = {Praktische Physik},
  volumes   = {3},
  volume    = {3}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\volcite{1}{Kohl}
\volcite{2}{Kohl}
\volcite{3}{Kohl}

\cite{Kohl1}
\cite{Kohl2}
\cite{Kohl3}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

My question is: How can I get the citation style in the second line without having to create explicit entries for each volume in the bib file? I thought this might be possible with `\volcite`.

Comment: I don't quite get your question. Can you clarify the output you'd like for: `\volcite{3}{Smith}`, `\volcite{3}[1]{Smith}`, `\cite{Smith}`, and `\cite[1]{Smith}`. If you don't want the volume printed in the citation, why use `\volcite` at all?

Comment: I'm with David on this, I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve. Why do you use `\volcite` when you don't want the output? (Note that the bibliography entry is no different whether you use `\cite` or `\volcite`?) Maybe you want to show us an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) of what you have so far, what `biblatex` style you use, etc. So we can all start from on the same page. You may also want to include a mock-up of the expected output in your MWE.

Comment: @DavidPurton, moewe: I added a MWE. Please let me know if the question is still unclear.

Comment: I must say to me it is still unclear what you want. Either you want to cite the entire three-volume work because it is unimportant which volumne you refer to, then use `\cite{Kohl}`. Or you want to refer to a specific volume in the bibliography, then use e.g. `\cite{Kohl2}`. Or you want to refer to the entire three-volume work, but occasionally make clear in the text which volume you refer to, then use `\cite[][vol.~2]{Kohl}` on those occasions and `\cite{Kohl}` otherwise. Is this still not what you want?

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf I want to cite specific volumes like with `\cite{Kohl2}`, but want to keep my bib file concise. I feel the entries `Kohl1–3` in the MWE are actually redundant information and that there might be a way to deduce specific volume-citations from the "parent" `Kohl` since all the information is already contained in this single entry. So the question might be more how to avoid the cumbersome creation of these volume-specific entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently only entries of a `.bib` file can really appear in the bibliography. That means that if you don't have a `.bib` entry for something, it can't appear as a separate entry in the bibliography. You can minimise duplication of data with `crossref`, your example then boils down to

```
@mvbook{Kohl,
  author    = {Kohlrausch, F.},
  title     = {Praktische Physik},
  volumes   = {3}
}
@book{Kohl1,
  crossref = {Kohl},
  volume   = {1},
}
@book{Kohl12,
  crossref = {Kohl},
  volume   = {2},
}
@book{Kohl3,
  crossref = {Kohl},
  volume   = {3},
}
```

This has the additional up-side of being able to specify differing info for the volumes. (Suppose for example, that one of the volumes is from a different year.)

Comment: You say "Currently only entries of a `.bib` file can appear in the bibliography." Are there any plans to add this functionality to `biblatex `? Apart from that, thanks for the hint using `crossref`, I didn't know about this.

Comment: @CorneliusSicker I don't think so. This principle seems to be fundamental to how BibTeX and `biblatex` work. Aside from that it would probably require a major overhaul of the code (currently Biber does the sorting for `biblatex` by reading the `.bib` file, if 'entries' can also come from the `.tex` itself, there would have to be a way to tell Biber about that). Furthermore, there would have to be a usable interface for the 'in-document' entries.

Comment: ... That said, Biber already does a bit to break up the strict `.tex`/`.bib` separation with its sourcemapping (only usable in the preamble, so no good for you, I'm afraid), where one can manipulate the (apparent content of the) `.bib` file from within the preamble of a `.tex` document. And then there is the [`notes2bib` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/notes2bib) that just writes a `.bib` on the fly from within a `.tex` document - seemingly breaking down the barriers between `.bib` and `.tex`.

Answer (score 0):

Does any of this maybe come close to what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[
    backend = biber,
    style = numeric-comp
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@MvBook{Kohl,
  author       = {Kohlrausch, F.},
  title        = {Praktische Physik},
  volumes      = {3},
  related      = {Kohl1,Kohl2,Kohl3},
  relatedtype  = {multivolume}
}
@Book{Kohl1,
  author       = {Kohlrausch, F.},
  title        = {Praktische Physik},
  volumes      = {3},
  volume       = {1}
}
@Book{Kohl2,
  author       = {Kohlrausch, F.},
  title        = {Praktische Physik},
  volumes      = {3},
  volume       = {2}
}
@Book{Kohl3,
  author       = {Kohlrausch, F.},
  title        = {Praktische Physik},
  volumes      = {3},
  volume       = {3}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Reference the entire work: \cite{Kohl}
Reference one volume only: \cite{Kohl2}
Reference volume in the entire work: \volcite{2}{Kohl}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

From all I read in the `BibLaTeX` documentation (i.e. sections 2.3.5 and 3.4) I do not think it is anticipated in any way not to have all subvolumes in the bib file. So what you seem to want is probably not possible (unless of course, you save the multivolume-book simply as book with information about the total number of volumes).

Comment: The second option you give is the output I'd like to achieve, but only using `Kohl`, not `Kohl2`. For my example with only three volumes it is no problem to generate the bib entries by hand, but imagine an encyclopedia with 30 volumes. Does one really have to create a separate entry for each cited volume to be able to get the same citation and bibliography entry as in your second example `[2]`?